# Simple addition in CSV using powershell 2.0

Tags: powershell

Given a csv-file of the following form:

example.csv

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
...
```

What is a powershell script I can use to add the first two elements together and update the same input file, like this:

example.csv

```
3,3,4
11,7,8
...
```

Answer (score 0):

pasteDcl.ps1:

```
$f1=gc col1.txt;$f2=gc col2.txt;for($i=0;$i-lt$f1.length;++$i){$f1[$i]+','+[string]::Join(",",($f2[$i] -split ',')[0..1])|ac colnew.txt}
```

command:

```
powershell .\pasteDcl.ps1
```

Result, colnew.txt:

```
1,2,3,4,3,3
5,6,7,8,11,7
```

col1.txt:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

col2.txt:

```
3,3,4
11,7,8
```

As far as I can see the story you are trying to forecast with a certain service. I think you can write a script to retrieve data in powershell.

And speaking of csv better represent it in the form of "data1"; "data2"; ... "DataN".
Your data is more commasplited text, or comma split csv. The last division bad if you use different national standards.